# ARM deployment of functions bot with MSDeploy fails most of the times

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

We are trying to deploy an Azure functions bot from the portal. We have used [this template](https://connectorprod.blob.core.windows.net/bot-packages/csharp-abs-functions_formbot.zip). Occasionally, the deployment succeeds and the bot runs, but about three out of four attempts, the deployment fails. Here is a screenshot of a failed deployment:

[image: Failed deployment]

After clicking 'here for details' we get:

```
{  
"code":"DeploymentFailed",
"message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
"details":
  [  
    {  
     "code":"Conflict",
     "message":"{\r\n
\"status\": \"failed\",\r\n
\"error\": {\r\n 
\"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n 
\"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.\",\r\n 
\"details\": [\r\n
{\r\n 
\"code\": \"Failed\",\r\n 
\"message\": \"AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net'\\r\\n
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext&amp; context)\\r\\n 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\\r\\n
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n 
at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.&lt;PostAsync&gt;d__33.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Kudu Files\\\\Private\\\\src\\\\master\\\\Kudu.Core\\\\Helpers\\\\PostDeploymentHelper.cs:line 440\\r\\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\\r\\n
at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.&lt;SyncFunctionsTriggers&gt;d__24.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Kudu Files\\\\Private\\\\src\\\\master\\\\Kudu.Core\\\\Helpers\\\\PostDeploymentHelper.cs:line 187\\r\\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n 
at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__23.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Kudu Files\\\\Private\\\\src\\\\master\\\\Kudu.Core\\\\Helpers\\\\PostDeploymentHelper.cs:line 111\\r\\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n 
at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.&lt;Run&gt;d__22.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Kudu Files\\\\Private\\\\src\\\\master\\\\Kudu.Core\\\\Helpers\\\\PostDeploymentHelper.cs:line 99\\r\\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\\r\\n 
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\"\r\n
}\r\n
]\r\n
}\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is it failing so often and what can we do to fix it?

**Edit 1:**
Kudu console output after nslookup:
[image: Kudu console output]

**Edit 2:**
[image: Deployments page in Azure]

Comment: Format your question (the details) it is far too long. The most important part is: "The remote name could not be resolved". Did you perform any research on that?

Comment: As a test, what happens if you go to Kudu Console for your Function App and run `nslookup ds-avabot-site-dlvrf32owk7cg.scm.azurewebsites.net`? Is it resolving from there?

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks for your suggestion. I get "Non-authoritative answer". See edit in the post.

Comment: @Rufus1123 that means that right now it's resolving correctly. But for some reason, at the time of your deployment, it probably wasn't.

Comment: When you see failures, is it always when running the ARM template to do the initial deployment (i.e. Function App doesn't exist before deployment), or also in update cases where App already exists?

Comment: @DavidEbbo Does that mean the steps done in the deployment are somehow in the wrong order? To answer your question: in both cases (initial deployment and update) the deployment may fail.

Comment: Root problem is likely https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2744, which is an unusual delay in DNS propagation. Please track that issue for progress. I think the reason you may still see it if you retry shortly after is DNS negative caching. If you wait a bit longer before retrying it should work consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this github thread (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2744), it is mentioned that this issue has been fixed. It will probably soon be released.

**Edit:**
Fix has been released as of 27-04-2018.

Answer (score 0):

Fix has been rolled out.   Let us know if still having issue.